# override the action of a backBarButtonItem in swift

Tags: ios, swift

without using the leftBarButtonItem and customizing the UINavigationController class, is there any other way to customize the action of the backBarButtonItem?

Comment: No, if you want to customize the action of the default back button, you need to subclass the navigation controller and override popViewControllerAnimated:. It would be better though to provide your own back button so the user doesn't get an unexpected result from the standard one.

Comment: You could also use "viewWillDisappear" if you want to add some Code.

Comment: cant use viewWillDisappear because you are already on the process of changing the view once you are in there. and you cant stop the process in there

Comment: I've used this extension with good success: https://github.com/onegray/UIViewController-BackButtonHandler